# A more elegant way to iterate through a list to compare 2 elements next to one another

Tags: java, loops, date, refactoring

I have a method which works in this way:

1. Take as an argument 3 params - a list with dates (sorted in ascending order) , interval unit and interval value
2. Check whether the next element doesn't exceed the previous date (interval). In other words, given the interval of 30 min, prev - 10:00, next 10:29 - iterate further. if next is 10:31 - break it and return the counter of dates in a row.

The code for it is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Date d1 = new Date();
    Date d2 = addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(d1, Calendar.MINUTE, 10, true);
    Date d3 = addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(d2, Calendar.MINUTE, 10, true);
    Date d4 = addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(d3, Calendar.MINUTE, 10, true);
    Date d5 = addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(d4, Calendar.MINUTE, 10, true);
    Date d6 = addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(d5, Calendar.MINUTE, 10, true);

    List<Date> threeDates = new ArrayList<>();
    threeDates.add(d1);
    threeDates.add(d2);
    threeDates.add(d3);
    threeDates.add(d4);
    threeDates.add(d5);
    threeDates.add(d6);

    System.out.println(returnDatesInARowCounter(threeDates, Calendar.MINUTE, 30));
}

private static int returnDatesInARowCounter(List<Date> allDates, int intervalBetween2DatesTimeUnit, int intervalValue)
{
    int datesInARowCounter = allDates.size() > 0 ? 1 : 0; // esp. this line (in case allDates is empty)
    Date lastDate = null;
    Date nextDate;

    Iterator<Date> iter = allDates.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        nextDate = iter.next();

        if (lastDate != null) // both lastDate и nextDate are initialized now
        {
            if(isNextIncidentInIntervalWithLastOneOrNot(lastDate, nextDate, intervalBetween2DatesTimeUnit, intervalValue, true))
            {
                datesInARowCounter += 1;
            }
            else break;
        }

        lastDate = nextDate;
    }

    return datesInARowCounter;
}

public static Date addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(Date dateToAddToOrSubtractFrom, int calendarTimeUnit, int value, boolean isAdd)
{
    if(!isAdd)
    {
        value = -value;
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(dateToAddToOrSubtractFrom);
    cal.add(calendarTimeUnit, value);
    return cal.getTime();
}

private static boolean isNextIncidentInIntervalWithLastOneOrNot(Date lastIncidentRegDate, Date nextIncidentRegDate, int intervalTimeUnit, int intervalValue, boolean isBetween)
{
    Date currentIncidentPlusInterval = addOrSubtractTimeUnitFromDate(lastIncidentRegDate, intervalTimeUnit, intervalValue, true);
    boolean betweenBool = isDateBetween(nextIncidentRegDate, lastIncidentRegDate, currentIncidentPlusInterval);

    return isBetween == betweenBool;
}

private static boolean isDateBetween(Date targetDate, Date startDate, Date endDate)
{
    return targetDate.compareTo(startDate) >= 0 && targetDate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0;
}
```

However, the code looks peculiar to me. Is the any way to make it look more readable?

Comment: you should use loop for adding instead of creating 6 different dates(d1 to d6)

Comment: Yeah, in main method it's hardcoded solely for testing purposes

Comment: If you have a working code and is looking for specific review, you might want to check https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: One change that I can see is that you can replace the `while` loop that's using an iterator with `foreach` loop, like this: `for (Date date : allDates)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 or newer, you can use the java.time-API instead. It's built-in support for "periods of time" makes the actual implementation much simpler.

```java
static int daysInARow(List<Instant> allInstants, Duration maxDifference) {
        int counter = allInstants.size() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        Instant previous = allInstants.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < allInstants.size(); i++) {
            Instant current = allInstants.get(i);
            if (Duration.between(previous, current).compareTo(maxDifference) > 0)
                break;
            counter++;
            previous = current;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

If you're using `java.util.Date` in other parts of your project, you can easily convert between `Instant`s by using

```java
Date#from(Instant)
```

and

```java
Date#toInstant()
```